# Correct phrase for "domesticated" opposition party

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-request

In Bangladesh, we use the word "গৃহপালিত" for an opposition party that was installed by a ruling regime through a rigged election. The main duty of this party is to give the vibe that the country is democratic. They do nothing that may harm the ruling party in anyway. So, what is the correct phrase in English for such an opposition party?

The word "গৃহপালিত" literally translates to pet, domestic, or domesticated. I have seen some of our English daily using the term domesticated for such a party. For example, [here](https://bdnews24.com/politics/2018/09/08/ershad-says-jatiya-party-would-no-more-be-domesticated-opposition). But I think there might be a better phrase that non native English speakers like me are not aware of.

Comment: To clarify, **(1)** Is it that the "Current Ruling Party" will "rig the elections" to again "win" , & let the "Opposition" Party "win" few places to remain the "Domesticated Opposition" ? Then it may be something like **"Caged Opposition"** !! Or **(2)** Is it that the "Current Ruling Party" will "rig the elections" to "lose" & let the "Opposition" win but not have real Power, which will remain with the "Current Ruling Party" ? Then it may be something like **"B-team"** !!

Comment: @Prem The current ruling party (say A party) rigged two consecutive elections (and are in power for 3rd consecutive terms). In the first one, the main opposition party (say B party) didn’t participate claiming that the election won't be fair and another smaller party (say J party that in fact is an ally of the ruling A party) won some seats and became the main opposition (so called domesticated) in the parliament.  In the second election, the B party participated but the election was heavily rigged and again J party became the opposition party. ...

Comment: ...So, what is the phrase for this 'domesticated' J party?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be a rant about one nation's internal politics.

Comment: It's not particular to politics, but _tame_ is sometimes used as a semi-jocular epithet to describe somebody who do somebody else's bidding, rather than show their independence. It is not used predicatively in this sense (i.e. you wouldn't normally say "He is tame"; but I can imagine somebody referring to "the governments' tame opposition", which is the same metaphor as the Bengali.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey If we assume good intentions, I think that's a little too harsh. The question can be edited to take out the more opinionated parts.

Comment: @ColinFine While I was searching for 'tame opposition', I came upon this [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loyal_opposition) that uses "loyal opposition". They used it for the same type of opposition party I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Imran: take care. That Wikipedia article gives two meanings of the phrase, and the other meaning is the only one I have ever met. Looking further, I find that the section "Loyal opposition in authoritarian regimes" was inserted by a single editor in February this year, with not a single reference to support the claim that the phrase is used in this way. I've had a look in the iWeb corpus, but I can't think of a way to search for the particular meaning short of looking at each instance in its context. The phrase _might_ have been used this way, but I've not so far found any evidence.

Comment: @Imran Colin is right. In the UK, the opposition party is often referred to as "The Loyal Opposition" or "Her Majesty's Loyal Opposition" but they are loyal to the Queen, not the party in power. They are anything but a puppet of the ruling party.

Comment: @ColinFine Hmm, I think I get it now. Will you convert your comment to an answer?

Comment: @PeterJennings - except at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a specific phrase for this in English.

We sometimes use *tame* attributively in a (sometimes jocular) fashion  to mean "having a function but not applying that function in an independent way); so if you said "a/the tame opposition", I think people would understand this to mean what you want to convey.

Answer (score 3):

Converting my Earlier Comment into a longer Comment !

**(Case 1)** The "Current Ruling Party X" will "rig the elections" to again "win" , & let the "Y Opposition" Party "win" few places to remain the "Domesticated Opposition" :
Then Y may be something like **"Caged Opposition" or "Toothless Tiger"**

**(Case 2)** The "Current Ruling Party X" will "rig the elections" to "lose" & let the "Y Opposition" win but not have real Power, which will remain with the "Current Ruling Party" :
Then Y may be something like **"Impotent Government" or "B-team of X"**

**(Case 3, which OP is concerned about)** The "Current Ruling Party X" will "rig the elections" to again "win" , & let the "Y Opposition" Party "win" few places, where Y (which is ally of X) will remain the "Domesticated Opposition" :
Then Y may be something like **"Pseudo Opposition" or "Sham Opposition"**

Comment: Yes, I think the word pseudo or sham depicts the whole scenario better.

Comment: +1 but note that these are "descriptive phrases" and not "What this is called in English".  There isn't a word to describe this state of affairs in English, any more than there is a native word in English for kimono.

Comment: Thanks for the +1 encouragement @JamesK ! This Question was tagged "phrase-request" & OP asked about "better phrase" or "correct phrase" ; I have given some suggestions but there can be no "Exact Correct Match" native term !!